# AngularJS Toggling fontAwesome class on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, font-awesome

I am trying to change the class on an element created with the font awesome library. Basically, I want on initial load the heart to not be filled in and have the class - 'far', then on click of button I want the heart to change to the class that fills the heart in - 'fas'. It does show the 'far' class on initial load, but does not change to the 'fas' class when the button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button class="favorite-btn" ng-click="favMovie()">
  <i ng-class="{'fas' : toggle, 'far' : !toggle}" class="fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("movieApp", []);
app.controller('DetailsController', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.toggle = false;
  $scope.favMovie = function() {
      console.log($scope.toggle);

      $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;

      console.log($scope.toggle);
    }
});
```

I have searched other stack questions/answers and nothing has helped.

This confirms in the console that it is in fact changing the toggle state (toggle === true || toggle === false), but not changing the class.

**Demo:**

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("movieApp", []);
app.controller('DetailsController', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.toggle = false;
  $scope.favMovie = function() {
   console.log($scope.toggle);
   
   $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
   
   console.log($scope.toggle);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

button {width:150px; height:150px; font-size:5em;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!--<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DetailsController">
    <button class="favorite-btn" ng-click="favMovie()">
      <i ng-class="{'fas' : toggle, 'far' : !toggle}" class="fa-heart"></i>
    </button>
  </body>
  
  <!-- {{heartClass}}  {'fas' : toggle, 'far' : !toggle} -->

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using FA icon as JS, the icon will be rendered as SVG format. So SVG is not a normal element as you expected and effect in Angular functionalities. You should try another way to handle this. Please check my code snippet bellow:

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("movieApp", []);
app.controller('DetailsController', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.toggle = false;
  $scope.favMovie = function() {
   $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
  }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

button {width:150px; height:150px; font-size:5em;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!--<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DetailsController">
    <button class="favorite-btn" ng-click="favMovie()">
      <span ng-if="!toggle"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
      <span ng-if="toggle"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
    </button>
  </body>
  
  <!-- {{heartClass}}  {'fas' : toggle, 'far' : !toggle} -->

</html>
```

Comment: Just what I needed, this worked perfectly. Thank you!